# method returning Layout or View

Tags: android, android-layout

The app I am trying to make, has got a lot of similar LinearLayouts and textViews that need to be created programmatically and placed on the screen in a specific order.

So I decided to define a method which returns one element, and for the furthur uses,I will put the method in some loop to produce the others. but when I create a view or layout this way, nothing shows up or sometimes the app crashes, as if it's been sent null to addView(). It only works when I create the View/Layout in onCreate() and then I use it right there afterwards.So , any ideas that I can use the method to creat my Layout/View? Because they are too many and it's not possible to create them one by one in onCreate()
 Here's the method:

```
public LinearLayout createLinearLayout(){
    TextView tv_day = new TextView(this);
    tv_day.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tv_day.setHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv_day.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    tv_day.setText("27");


    LinearLayout ll_horizontal = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll_horizontal_params = new       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll_horizontal.setLayoutParams(ll_horizontal_params);
    ll_horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    ll_horizontal.addView(tv_day);
    return ll_horizontal;
}
```

and this is onCreate() which doesn't add any linear layouts with a textView in it :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_month_view);
    LinearLayout ll= createLinearLayout();

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_month_view);
    mainLayout.addView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help
 - add an empty linear layout in XML with some id.
 - reference that layout in code
 - add elements to that layout dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Hey was just checking your code. Its working perfectly now just try this method.

```
public LinearLayout createLinearLayout(){
    TextView tv_day = new TextView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv_day.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    tv_day.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv_day.setText("27");


    LinearLayout ll_horizontal = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll_horizontal_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll_horizontal.setLayoutParams(ll_horizontal_params);
    ll_horizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    ll_horizontal.addView(tv_day);
    return ll_horizontal;
}
```